# split string with regex

Tags: regex, r, strsplit

I'm looking to split a string of a generic form, where the square brackets denote the "sections" of the string. Ex:

```
x <- "[a] + [bc] + 1"
```

And return a character vector that looks like:

```
"[a]"  " + "  "[bc]" " + 1"
```

EDIT: Ended up using this:

```
x <- "[a] + [bc] + 1"
x <- gsub("\\[",",[",x)
x <- gsub("\\]","],",x)
strsplit(x,",")
```

Comment: Please post what you ended up using as an answer rather than an edit to the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen TylerRinker's code and suspect it may be more clear than this but this may serve as way to learn a different set of functions. (I liked his better before I noticed that it split on spaces.)  I tried adapting this to work with `strsplit` but that function always removes the separators. 
Maybe this could be adapted to make a `newstrsplit` that splits at the separators but leaves them in? Probably need to not split at first or last position and distinguish between opening and closing separators.

```
scan(text=   # use scan to separate after insertion of commas
            gsub("\\]", "],",   # put commas in after "]"'s
            gsub(".\\[", ",[",  x)) ,  # add commas before "[" unless at first position
        what="", sep=",")    # tell scan this character argument and separators are ","
#Read 4 items
#[1] "[a]"  " +"   "[bc]" " + 1"
```

Comment: I like this approach as it is not dependent on white space for splitting. Maintaining the white space in the output was not important for this task, so I modified this to work with `strplit`:

Comment: Thanks for the positive comment, but I consider @juba's a better answer. I'm going to use it to construct a simple parsing function that accepts a pair of arguments to signal beginning and ending delimiters that will be preserved.

Answer (score 5):

This is one lazy approach:

```
FUN <- function(x) {
    all <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\\s+"))
    last <- paste(c(" ", tail(all, 2)), collapse="")
    c(head(all, -2), last)
}

x <- "[a] + [bc] + 1"    
FUN(x)

## > FUN(x)
## [1] "[a]"  "+"    "[bc]" " +1"
```

Comment: You say 'lazy' because you are using the spaces rather than using brackets to separate?

Comment: Yes ( no real intense regexing)

Answer (score 5):

You can compute the split points manually and use `substring` :

```
split.pos <- gregexpr('\\[.*?]',x)[[1]]
split.length <- attr(split.pos, "match.length")
split.start <- sort(c(split.pos, split.pos+split.length))
split.end <- c(split.start[-1]-1, nchar(x))
substring(x,split.start,split.end)
#  [1] "[a]"  " + "  "[bc]" " + 1"
```

Comment: There we go. Great progress toward making a 'newsplit'. Not that I understand it fully, but I thought `gregexpr` would be useful. I was surprised you didn't need to use "\\]" in the pattern.

Comment: I think `]` doesn't need to be escaped because it is not interpreted as an end of character class due to the fact that `[` is. Hmm, not sure I'm very clear :-)

Comment: I had the same thought, but it suggests that "specialness" is more context dependent than I would have expected.

Answer (score 5):

And here's a version that splits on the brackets AND keeps them in the result, using positive lookahead and lookbehind:

```
splitme <- function(x) {
  x <- unlist(strsplit(x, "(?=\\[)", perl=TRUE))
  x <- unlist(strsplit(x, "(?<=\\])", perl=TRUE))
  for (i in which(x=="[")) {
    x[i+1] <- paste(x[i], x[i+1], sep="")
  }
  x[-which(x=="[")]
}
splitme(x)
#[1] "[a]"  " + "  "[bc]" " + 1"
```