# manually split and then use substring to split a character sting, ready-made function to do this?

Tags: r

This is the string I want to split:

`b[1]
[1] "County                           January 2016 February 2016         March 2016         April 2016       May 2016           June 2016         July 2016      August 2016 September 2016 October 2016             November 2016 December 2016\r"`

From this post [split string with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573887/split-string-with-regex) I gather there is no ready-made function to do so, I just want to confirm than.

Here is my code

```
split.pos <- gregexpr("County|([aA-zZ]{1,} [0-9]{4,})", b[1], perl = FALSE)

split.length <- attr(split.pos[[1]], "match.length")

split.start <- split.pos[[1]][1:length(split.pos[[1]])]

substring(b[1], split.start, split.start+split.length)
 [1] "County "         "January 2016 "   "February 2016 "  "March 2016 "    
 [5] "April 2016 "     "May 2016 "       "June 2016 "      "July 2016 "     
 [9] "August 2016 "    "September 2016 " "October 2016 "   "November 2016 " 
[13] "December 2016\r
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: What is the splitting criteria? Is your data tab-delimited? Fixed-width? Always non-numeric, non-spaced value followed optionally by a number? What is your criteria for "better"?

Comment: Thanks for urging me to think properly about this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` with regex lookaround

```
strsplit(b, "(?<=[0-9])\\s+|\\s+(?=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "County"         "January 2016"   "February 2016"  "March 2016"     "April 2016"     "May 2016"       "June 2016"      "July 2016"      "August 2016"   
#[10] "September 2016" "October 2016"   "November 2016"  "December 2016"
```

#### data

```
b <- "County                           January 2016 February 2016         March 2016         April 2016       May 2016           June 2016         July 2016      August 2016 September 2016 October 2016             November 2016 December 2016\r"
```