# Split a string by a sign and word

Tags: r, string, split

I have to extract parts of a string in R based on a symbol and a word. I have a name such as

```
s <-"++can+you+please-help +me"
```

and the output would be:

```
"+ can" "+you" "+please" "-help" "+me"
```

where all words with the corresponding symbol before are shown. I've tried to use the strsplit and sub functions but I´m struggling in getting the output that I want. Can you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Please share what you tried in order not to repeat the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573887/split-string-with-regex

Comment: Why is there a space with `"+ can"`. Did you intend to remove one of the plus sign and replace it with that space? `unlist(strsplit(s, split="(?<=\\w)\\s*(?=[+-]+)", perl=T))` gets very close.

Comment: The space between "+" and "can" was a typing error. my apologies for that. My intention was only to get one "+" out of the "++" and get "+can" and not "+ can".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do**

```
library(stringi)
result = unlist(stri_match_all(regex = "\\W\\w+",str = s))
```

**Result**

```
> result
[1] "+can"    "+you"    "+please" "-help"   "+me"
```

**No symbols**

If you only want the words (no symbols), do:

```
result = unlist(stri_match_all(regex = "\\w+",str = s))

result
[1] "can"    "you"    "please" "help"   "me"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `base R`

```
regmatches(s, gregexpr("[[:punct:]]\\w+", s))[[1]]  
#[1] "+can"    "+you"    "+please" "-help"   "+me"
```

Comment: Thank you! it works. Is there any website where I can have a nice explanation and good examples on how to write the patterns that I´m looking for in R?