# Regex to split string by character and retaining content inside square brackets

Tags: r, regex, string, split, character

Hello I have a string as a linux command like this

```
x <- "cd/etc/init[BKSP][BKSP]it.d[ENTER]"
```

I want to split the string by character and keep the content inside of the square bracket intact. Basically I want to retain the command press. The result would look some thing like this if using `str_split`:

```
c("c","d","/","e","t","c","i",......"BKSP","BKSP","i","t",".", "d", "ENTER")
```

Can someone help me with this problem? I've been playing with regex and haven't figured out how to achieve this.

I tried `/.*?[^[A-Z*?]/` but I didn’t do the trick. I’m also trying to add the delimiter to the matching group to split the string, too.

Comment: Would you share you have tried?

Comment: I tried /.*?[^[A-Z*?]/ but I didn’t do the trick. I’m also trying to add the delimier to the matchinh group to split the string too.

Comment: I can't get it in one step `strsplit(gsub('(?|\\[(\\w+)\\]|(.))', '\\1,', x, perl = TRUE), ',')`

Comment: @rawr this is perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Match and capture all substrings inside brackets and also capture any other character inside a [*branch reset group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html). Then, remove the outer square bracekts in the found matches:

```
> x <- c("cd/etc/init[BKSP][BKSP]it.d[ENTER]", "abc]", "[abc")
> matches <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?s)(?|\\[([^][]*)]|(.))", x, perl=TRUE))
> sapply(matches, sub, pattern="\\[(.*)\\]", replacement="\\1")
[[1]]
 [1] "c"     "d"     "/"     "e"     "t"     "c"     "/"     "i"     "n"     "i"     "t"     "BKSP"  "BKSP"  "i"     "t"     "."     "d"     "ENTER"

[[2]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "]"

[[3]]
[1] "[" "a" "b" "c"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p9L0E7/1). Details:

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier to let `.` match line break chars, too
- `(?|\[([^][]*)]|(.))` - a  branch reset group where capturing group IDs in different alternation branches have idetnical IDs:

  - `\[([^][]*)]` - a `[` followed with any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` captured into Group 1 and then `]`
  - `|` - or
  - `(.)` - any char (again, Group 1).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my rather long-winded solution to your problem (I adapted approach from this post: [split string with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573887/split-string-with-regex))

```
x <- "[a] + [bc] + 1"

foo <- function(x){
  #Mark square brackets with commas
  x <- gsub("\\[",",[",x)
  x <- gsub("\\]","],",x)

  #Separate the string based on commas
  x <- unlist(strsplit(x,","))

  #Find which vector elements contain brackets
  ind <- grepl("\\[.*\\]", x)

  y <- character()
  for (a in seq_along(x)){
    if (nchar(x[a])!=0){
      if (ind[a]){
        y <- c(y, x[a]) #Store original character
      } else {
        y <- c(y, unlist(strsplit(x[a], ""))) #Store split character
      }
    }
  }

  #Remove the brackets
  y <- gsub("\\[", "", y)
  y <- gsub("\\]", "", y)
  return(y)
}
```